# What "type" of thing are injective, surjective, bijective?

Tags: functions

This is more a vocab question than anything else but what "type" of thing are injective, surjective, bijective. I fully understand what these words mean but I'm looking for a word to describe the type of properties these might be. Basically "odd and even" is to "parity" as "injective, surjective, bijective" is to what? Thank you all!

Comment: Function properties?

Comment: I have never heard a word which lumps these adjectives together in a way similar to how "parity" lumps "even" and "odd", or "sign" lumps "positive" and "negative".  Nor have I ever felt the *lack* of such a word.  Is there any particular reason why you think that such a term exists?  *should* exist?  What problem is being solved here?

Comment: Coin the neologism "jectivity". Everyone will know what it means.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I was asked for an assignment to describe which of a set of functions had which of these properties. The word would just have made a few sentences flow nicer, but I was also just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that injectivity, surjectivity, and bijectivity are forms of "invertibility". Being injective is the same as having a left-inverse, surjective is the same as having a right-inverse, and being bijective is the same as having both left and right inverses.

Comment: +1 i was going to suggest cancellativity for the same reason. but really the point is there is no standard word for this the way OP might hope.

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea to use "invertibility" in this manner, since "invertible" is already typically used synonymously with "injective".

Comment: @hunter - Same, but "cancelability" was the version that popped into my mind, although that's not a standard word either.